# Adding a redirect-uri to a Dropbox application

Tags: oauth-2.0, dropbox

I have a working Dropbox application, using oauth. I am extending the application and have added a new redirect-uri in the App Console. I am absolutely sure that the redirect uri is correct, but I am getting a 400 Invalid redirect-uri error. My uri begins with https:// as required.

Is there a delay before new redirect uris take effect?

This is the error:

```
More details for developers

 Invalid redirect_uri: u'https://shareddom.ws/mse/auth/guest_portal.php'. It must exactly match one of the redirect URIs you've pre-configured for your app (including the path)
```

This the uri, cut and pasted from the App Console:

```
https://shareddom.ws/mse/auth/guest_portal.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there should be any delay at all (certainly no more than a few seconds at most).

Those two strings appear to be identical, so my guess would be that the redirect URI isn't in the right place (or maybe under the right app?). Double check that the app key you're using matches the app key you're looking at in the App Console and that redirect URI is under the "OAuth 2 Redirect URIs" section of the page.

If you're still having trouble, I'd suggest opening a support ticket so we can double check the app details for you: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact.

Comment: Thank you! I have two apps, under different accounts, and was updating the wrong one..